# Как сделать случайные ошибки в текстовом файле?

Tags: python

У меня задача - открыть с бинарном режиме txt-файл и изменить его любым способом(исказить как-то, чтобы он не был читаемым).

На вход программе подается txt-файл, содержащий некоторый текст. Сформируйте новый файл, в который сохраните этот искажённый текст, полученный из исходного.

Вот пример с bmp, он норм работает, искажает в негатив и выдаёт мне информацию в битах и байтах.

```
 with open('bmp_file.bmp', mode='rb') as inputfile:
        header = inputfile.read(54)
        res = [255 - val for val in inputfile.read()]
        with  open("bmp_file_negative.bmp", mode="wb") as outputfile:
            outputfile.write(header)
            outputfile.write(bytes(res))
```

Как сделать такое с текстовым файлом? чтобы текст изменился с какой-то определенной вероятностью? Он может измениться, а может и нет. Короче, чтобы ошибки были случайными ( ошибки должны идти через биты '0' и '1')

Comment: "всегда будет одно и тоже"... т.е. вы не собираетесь потом это расшифровывать?.. тогда забейте его рандомными символами

Comment: Берёте какую-нибудь текстовую фразу и делаете посимвольно `XOR` вашего текста и взятой столько раз этой фразы сколько нужно, чтобы было столько же символов, сколько в тексте. Это в общем известный метод шифровки.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

.... val ^ (random.randrange(256) * random.randrange(2)) for val in ...
```